# Python Modules on a Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I am trying to create a python program for my Casio fx-9750GIII calculator that computes the molar mass of a given chemical formula. To do this I need more methods for strings from curses.ascii such as isalpha. Unfortunately I don't know how modules work on a non-networked device. Do I just need to download a file and put it on the calculator for an import statement to work or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: The function `isalpha()` already exists in Python, it is a method of the `str` class.

Comment: You can view the standard library here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/
This contains libraries included with python that will be present on any device which python is installed on (spare some specialized installations)

Comment: Note that the calculator is probably running something like [micropython](https://micropython.org/) (the [product press release](https://www.casio.com/news/detail/making-math-and-science-easy-casio-introduces-new-all-in-one-graphing-calculator) says "With the addition of the Python Add-In, users have access to a light-weight version of a modern programming language. Although it does not support all of the functions, command, modules, and libraries of Python™, it will be familiar to those who have used this programming language".

Comment: ...which suggests it probably *does not* have all the methods you would find in the regular python standard library.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter Lecdi said, it is a native python string method, I just made the mistake of typing isalpha() without a string beforehand.